# slideDown/slideUp for scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scroll, slide, slidedown, slideup

I wish my navbar had an effect slideDown instead of fideIn. It is possible?

This is the code with .fideIn:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#navbar").hide();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $("#navbar").fadeIn(500);

        if ($("body").scrollTop() == 0) {
            $("#navbar").fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vb986uth/2/)

I tried to change .fadeIn -> slideDown but the effect isn't seen. Why? I make some mistakes? Or it is impossible to put this kind of effect?

Comment: Please provide a demonstration of the problem, including your HTML in a simplified form. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vb986uth/2/

Comment: What would I click on in that demo? Please remove all unrelated code and design elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your are using `position:fixed;` In which case you will likely want to specify a width if you are testing with no content on `#navbar`. Here is a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/82xara3x/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#navbar").hide();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $("#navbar").stop().slideDown(500);

        if ($("body").scrollTop() == 0) {
            $("#navbar").stop().slideUp(500);
        }
    });
});

#navbar {
    background: #000;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Scroll down and you should see it. Hope this helps!

**Edit:** 
Showing your HTML and CSS would help greatly in determining your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this brother

```
$( window ).scroll( function(){  
      if( $( this ).scrollTop() > 1 ){
          $("#navbar").animate({top:0}, 800 );
      }else{
          $("#navbar").animate({top:'-100%'}, 800 );
      }  
});
```